# Unable to insert form values in to database Joomla 3

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, database, form, custom-module

I am creating a custom joomla module based on form submission 
but i am having some problems in inserting the values 
I have a html form which has certain fieldsets which pass values to mod_score.php which checks for empty validation and proceeds for helper.php where i have the function for inserting the form values.


Testing it on my localhost (XAMPP )

Version 3.4

Template Protostar

```
  // This is the class

class modScoreCardHelper
        {
    function saveCard($params)
        {
        $input= new JInput;
        $match_id           =   $input->get('match_id',null);
        $match_time         =   $input->get('match_time',null);
        $match_venue        =   $input->get('match_venue',null);
        $match_team_one     =   $input->get('match_team_one',null);
        $match_team_two     =   $input->get('match_team_two',null);
        $match_result       =   $input->get('match_result',null);
        $match_umpire_one   =   $input->get('match_umpire_one',null);
        $match_umpire_two   =   $input->get('match_umpire_two',null);
        $match_mom          =   $input->get('match_mom',null);
        $match_toss         =   $input->get('match_toss',null);
        $match_fow          =   $input->get('match_fow',null);
        $match_comments     =   $input->get('match_comments',null);
        $match_debutants    =   $input->get('match_debutants',null);


        // Get a db connection.
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        echo 'starting to insert in db';
        // Create a new query object.
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        // Insert columns.
        $columns = array('match_id', 'match_time', 'match_venue', 'match_result','match_team_one',
                'match_team_two','match_umpire_one','match_mom','match_comments','match_debutants',
                'match_umpire_two','match_toss','match_fow');



        $values = array($match_id, $match_time, $match_venue,$match_result,$match_team_one,
                $match_team_two,$match_umpire_one,$match_mom,$match_comments,
                $match_debutants,$match_umpire_two,$match_toss,$match_fow);




        // Prepare the insert query.
        $query->insert($db->quoteName('#__match_record'))
          ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
         ->values(implode(',', $values));

        // Set the query using our newly populated query object and execute it.
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $db->execute();


        }
    }
```

I simply copied the query in phpmyadmin and executed the code it gave me error 1064 as it is showing on the site.I searched a lot on google and added double quotes to  the column values field like "MI "," RCB " in phpmyadmin and the query executed sucessfully .there but i do not know how to add double quotes.Also in the query it is deleting the spaces in the values 

For example : actual value = MI won becomes MIwon.

how to remove those spaces and double quotes in my query and remove this error
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Are you sure all the columns you have defined such as `match_id` exist? Have you also ensured that all the values are being pulled correctly? Try `var_dump($match_id);` and see what the outcome is

Comment: Yes I have checked all the columns.Where should i add this var_dump. In my helper.php or mod_score.php !

Comment: Add it before your database query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your $input with following:

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input
```

Use `$db->quote($name_of_your_value_var);`

So your $values will be as follows:

```
$values = array($match_id, $db->quote($match_time), $db->quote($match_venue),$db->quote($match_result),$db->quote($match_team_one),
                $db->quote($match_team_two),$db->quote($match_umpire_one),$db->quote($match_mom),$db->quote($match_comments),
                $db->quote($match_debutants),$db->quote($match_umpire_two),$db->quote($match_toss),$db->quote($match_fow));
```

You can omit `$db->quote` if you are passing integer to the database. for e.g. I've not added `$db->quote` for `$match_id`. (assuming you are passing integer in that variable)

Also, I would suggest you to use [JTable](https://docs.joomla.org/J1.5:Using_the_JTable_class) method for CRUD operations on database. It will surely make your life easier.

Comment: It worked but it is still storing values in the database like MIwon instead of MI won. Thank your for help !

Comment: What is the method of your form? GET or POST? You should first consider printing $values array with print_r($values) and provide the output here.

Comment: post ! okay i am going to try that !

Answer (score 2):

Just a little to expand on @Sahil Purav's answer. The reason why your values might not be being stored as they should is because you need to define a filter in your inputs.

Try adding `RAW` to all of them, like so:

```
$match_id           =   $input->get('match_id', null, 'RAW');
$match_time         =   $input->get('match_time', null, 'RAW');
$match_venue        =   $input->get('match_venue', null, 'RAW');
$match_team_one     =   $input->get('match_team_one', null, 'RAW');
$match_team_two     =   $input->get('match_team_two' null, 'RAW');
$match_result       =   $input->get('match_result', null, 'RAW');
$match_umpire_one   =   $input->get('match_umpire_one', null, 'RAW');
$match_umpire_two   =   $input->get('match_umpire_two', null, 'RAW');
$match_mom          =   $input->get('match_mom', null, 'RAW');
$match_toss         =   $input->get('match_toss', null, 'RAW');
$match_fow          =   $input->get('match_fow', null, 'RAW');
$match_comments     =   $input->get('match_comments', null, 'RAW');
$match_debutants    =   $input->get('match_debutants', null, 'RAW');
```

Comment: Yes sir that worked !

Comment: Awesome, I missed that part @Lodder :)

Comment: Perfect answer, It worked like a charm

Comment: @DavidAddoteye - glad it helped ;)

Comment: $input->get('match_mom', null, 'RAW') is good but not safe. you can use 
$input->get('match_mom', null, 'STRING') if you are passing strings in a form name or sentence. 
$input->get('match_id', null, 'INT') if you are passing integer. 
You can get full details of the filters here
https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput